# Dynamically change the height parameter in JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The Jquery Lightbox script and examples are here: http://www.aerowebstudio.net/codecanyon/jquery.lightbox/.

I pass a few parameters to the JQuery that controls the lightbox plugin in the id from the hyperlink. The last substring (substrk[2]) on the id is the height. I can pass the value but the plugin's height stretches beyond the screen in height. If I don't plug in the height dynamically and put in a static number, the plugin works fine.

I also tried to delay the function from firing with a timer just in case that was the problem, but it wouldn't fire at all

```
<a class="lk" id="blah_blahh_68" href="javascript:void(0);">some link</a>

$(function(){
$(".lk").click(function(){
var lik = this.id;
var substrk = lik.split('_');
var intheight = substrk[2];
var strlinkk = "blah.php?id=" + substrk[0] + "&id2=" + substrk[1];
$.lightbox(strlinkk,{
'width'       : 474,
'height'      : intheight,
'autoresize'  : false
});
return false;
});
});
```

Unfortunately I dont see a good way to do this. Concatenating 'px' to the string doesn't work, nor does adding a short timeout

I had to do IF / ELSE statements to solve my problem. The IF THEN statements work, but it's not pretty. This works for me because I know the heights are in increments of 68px

```
$(function(){
$(".lk").click(function(){
var lik = this.id;
var substrk = lik.split('_');
var intheight = substrk[2];
var strlinkk = "blah.php?id=" + substrk[0] + "&id2=" + substrk[1];

if (intheight=68){

$.lightbox(strlinkk,{
'width'       : 474,
'height'      : 68,
'autoresize'  : false
});
return false;
});
});

}else if (intheight=136){

$.lightbox(strlinkk,{
'width'       : 474,
'height'      : 136,
'autoresize'  : false
});
return false;
});
});

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var intheight = substrk[2] + "px";
```

Also, just do a quick check at what substrk[2] is returning but throwing in a:

```
alert(substrk[2]);
```

it might be as simple as its throwing up something weird.